# Using JQuery on JavaScript variables

Tags: jquery

```
$.getJSON('ajax_popup.php', function(data)
{
    var popupDiv = decodeURIComponent(data.data);
    $('body').append( popupDiv );
});
```

This piece of code returns `<div>` element that has other XHTML elements inside. It is returned in JSON format with JQuery. The returned XHTML from `data.data` is stored into JavaScript variable by first decoding UTF-8 encoded data. The DIV element is a custom popup window. The above code works, BUT I want to make it draggable using JQuery UI's .draggable() method, but I don't know where to use it and how to make it work in this case.

I've tried:

```
popupDiv.draggable();
```

But it didn't work.

And:

```
$('body').append( popupDiv ).draggable();
```

But it made the body element draggable :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(popupDiv).draggable();
```

Comment: `$('body').append( $(popupDiv).draggable() );` Worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `jQuery` function can turn text into jQuery extended DOM elements. So:

```
$.getJSON( 'ajax_popup.php', function( data ) {
  var popupDiv = decodeURIComponent( data.data );
  $('body').append( $(popupDiv).draggable() );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert javascript variable to jquery object, use `$()`
Refer to [javascript variable to jQuery object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005437/javascript-variable-to-jquery-object)