# javascript variable to jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, fragment

How can I take this javascript variable and

1. convert it into jQuery object  $(myFragment)
2. change the id attribute from "fragment" to "fragment1" ?

> ```
> myFragment = "\
> <div id='fragment'>\
> <input type='hidden' id='preBeginDtlFields' name='BeginDtlFields'\
>  value=''  />\
> <input type='hidden' id='preGroup' name='GRP' value='' />\
> </div>";
> ```

Comment: Until you insert it into the DOM it is merely a string. Treat it as a string (you can use .replace) , or insert it onto the DOM and manipulate it with JS or jQuery.

Answer (score 15):

1. To convert to jQuery object:

   ```
   $(myFragment);
   ```
2. To change the id:

   ```
   $(myFragment).attr('id', 'fragment1');
   ```

Comment: how to convert a jQuery object back to JavaScript variable?

Answer (score 3):

To convert the string to HTML element pass it to jQuery function as parameter and it will return you a html element wrapped as a jQuery object. Then you can use all the regular jQuery functions to change the element.

Try this:

```
var myFragment = "\
<div id='fragment'>\
<input type='hidden' id='preBeginDtlFields' name='BeginDtlFields'\
 value=''  />\
<input type='hidden' id='preGroup' name='GRP' value='' />\
</div>";
var $myFragment = $(myFragment).appendTo("body");
$myFragment.attr("id", "new-id");
$("#new-id").text("It works!!!");
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xhC7D/

Comment: I'll try this, but I would prefer not to append it to DOM because I am using jQuery Mobile which seems to modify html on the DOM.